# SVG donut slice changing color on hover

Tags: svg, donut-chart

I have a simple SVG donut with 5 equal slices placed using stroke-dashoffset="xx". The donut itself looks OK but when I try to add some hover changes to each slice, for example, simple changing of the stroke color:

```
donut-piece:hover {
  stroke: #fc7822;
}
```

It doesn't work very well since all circles are basically on top of each other. Is there a way to make it work as expected?

Here is the donut code:

```css
.donut-piece:hover {
  stroke: #fc7822;
}
```

```html
<svg width="700" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
   <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="10"></circle>

   <circle class="donut-data donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#535f7f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="3"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-device donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#556180" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="18"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-physical donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#51628f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="33"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-network donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#556180" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="48"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-iot donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#535f7f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="63"></circle>

</svg>
```

Comment: I turned your code block into a snippet. And I have fixed the missing `.` in your CSS rule definition - I assume that was just a typo (?)

Comment: yes, it was a typo, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is highlighting the correct segment when you are outside the radius of the circle.  However when the pointer is inside the circle radius, the browser thinks you are 
hovering over the bottom-left segment. This corresponds to the last circle in your SVG file.

You are getting this effect because you have set the `fill` of your circles to `transparent`.  SVG's hover testing will only ignore a `fill` or a `stroke` when it is set to `none`.  They are not treated as being equivalent.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

**1. Change the fill colour of your circles to `"none"`**

```css
.donut-piece:hover {
  stroke: #fc7822;
}
```

```html
<svg width="700" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
   <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="10"></circle>

   <circle class="donut-data donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="none" stroke="#535f7f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="3"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-device donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="none" stroke="#556180" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="18"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-physical donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="none" stroke="#51628f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="33"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-network donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="none" stroke="#556180" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="48"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-iot donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="none" stroke="#535f7f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="63"></circle>

</svg>
```

**2. Tell the browser to ignore the fill for mouse events**

You can do that by setting `pointer-events: visibleStroke;`.  The default value for `pointer-events` is `visiblePainted`, which tests for both the fill and the stroke.

[You can read more about `pointer-events` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

```css
.donut-piece {
  pointer-events: visibleStroke;
}

.donut-piece:hover {
  stroke: #fc7822;
}
```

```html
<svg width="700" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
   <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="10"></circle>

   <circle class="donut-data donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#535f7f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="3"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-device donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#556180" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="18"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-physical donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#51628f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="33"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-network donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#556180" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="48"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-iot donut-piece" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#535f7f" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="63"></circle>

</svg>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I implemented the first approach, works perfectly.

Comment: Why is this not very accurate (Tested in Chrome and Firefox) ? I've made a donut circle with 60 slices. Where at offset 0 it works fine, but how higher the offset, how worse the accuracy gets.

Comment: Possibly because the test that browsers use for whether you are hovering over a particular dash segment of a stroke, is not very accurate.  I suspect they use a lot of approximations to speed up the test.  I would urge you not to use strokes to construct your segments.  Do it properly and use filled shapes instead.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau - do you know of an example of constructing segments with filled shapes instead of strokes? I'm having the same issue with hover accuracy.

Comment: I whipped up a mini library for creating donut graphs using filled shapes. You can find it here: https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/details/MWwrBzN  See the code for documentation of the methods.